# Searching Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, search, key

I am trying to calculate the percent change in values within a dictionary created from a .csv. In the .csv, years are stored under headers in the format 'yr19--'. However, when I search for values using the code below, every time I get "Year not found". 
[Dictionary in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUfXj.jpg)

```
#Step 4. Allow user to choose years
myYear1 = ('yr'+(input('Pick a year between 1970 and 2005 that ends in "0" or "5": ')))
myYear2 = ('yr'+(input('Now, pick another: ')))
#print('Let\'s calculate the percent change in population between',myYear1,'and',myYear2,'.')

#Step 1. Import and read CityPop.csv with open(r'C:\Users\Megan\Desktop\Megan3\CityPop.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    #Step 2. Build dictionary to store .csv data
    worldCities = {}

    #Step 3. Use field names from .csv to create key and access attribute values
    for row in reader:
            worldCities[row['label']] = dict(row)

    #Step 5. Search dictionary for years
    if myYear1 in worldCities:

    #Step 6. Make sure input corresponds to file, return values to user
            yr1Val = (worldCities[row['myYear1']])
            print(yr1Val)
    else:
            print('Year not found.')
```

Is this the correct way to search the dictionary? Do I need to do something differently because the headers are technically keys?

Comment: Show us what is `reader` and `worldCities`  in your code?

Comment: Gotcha. Added link in question!

Comment: We need to see the python representation of the data as shotgunner suggested, since the CSV doesn't easily translate. Also consider correcting your code indentation / formatting.

Comment: Oops... I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code indentation is wrong. last `if` must be inside of the `for` loop scope. you can search year like this:

```
for row in reader:
    worldCities[row['label']] = dict(row)
    if myYear1 in worldCities[row['label']].keys():
        yr1Val = worldCities[row['label']][myYear1]
        print(yr1Val)
    else:
        print('Year not found.')
```